# Sending a summary of SQL Server Agent job failures

Tags: sql-server, notifications, sql-server-agent

SQL Server Agent allows you to create Notifications at the moment a Job succeeds or fails, but I'd like to create a regular notification that sends a summary of the events for those who are one step removed from server maintenance.

Is there a way to setup summary notifications that spell out which jobs failed over the last 24 hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several system stored procedures that you might be able to use or you could query directly against the system tables. If you have SSRS available then put together a report using those queries and you can have it on-demand or scheduled to be emailed to the necessary people at whatever time is right for you.

Specifically, check out **sp_help_jobhistory** and **sp_help_jobhistory_full** in msdb.

I'd be surprised if you couldn't use Google to find a demo of setting this up.